# how do I create a condition in oracledb?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

How do i create a condition on oracle db? I'm new on this db.
I already create table called vehicle_parked, but i want to trigger vehicle number as NULL if parkedOnSite value is 'F' and the structure like this

**vehicle_parked**

```
 - parked_id number(4) PK
 - arrivalTime date
 - parkedOnSite varchar(1) // value will be T/F
 - vehicle_number varchar(8)
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, You want a trigger for the same or Update statement?

Comment: Are you trying to create a trigger for automatically set the vehicle number to null on insert/update if the flag is F? Or a check constraint to stop a user trying to create a not-null value (and maybe conversely a null value if the flag is T)? Or to replace a not-null value with null when you query the table if the flag is F? How far have you got already?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, i want to create a trigger for automatically set the vehicle number to null on insert/update if the flag is F, but if T i need to insert vehicle number

Comment: @AnkitBajpai trigger on insert. Because i had a case if vehicle parked on site is True, vehicle number will be recorded. if F, so i dont need to insert vehicle number

Comment: Do you also need to stop the flag being 'T' if there is no vehicle number? What should happen if that happens? And why only on insert, don't you need to check/enforce this on update too?

Comment: @AlexPoole well, my case like this "if they have parked their car in
the official car park, the registration number of the vehicle is also recorded", so it means if they don't park offsite i don't need to put vehicle number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily manipulate your data by creating a `DML trigger` that fires before your data is inserted into table, and changes data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_vehicle_parked
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON vehicle_parked
   FOR EACH ROW    
DECLARE

BEGIN
  if :new.parkedOnSite = 'F' then
   :new.vehicle_number := null;
  end if;
END;
/
```

In triggers, besides `:new`, we can use `:old` pseudo codes. They stand for the values of the columns before(`:old`) or after(`:new`) DML statements issued.
Especially for an `update` or `delete` trigger you may compare your column's old and new values in a trigger as in the example :

```
if ( nvl(:old.vehicle_number,0) != nvl(:new.vehicle_number,0) ) then
  go_on_with_statement ....
```